# UITableView does not scroll to bottom (Swift IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My UITableView does not scroll to the bottom and stops before all the content can be displayed (cuts off the last few rows). I have checked that my UITableView is equal to the screen size, but the content size is greater than screen and table height. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Do you have a `UITabBar` at the bottom of your screen? This content may be covered by the bar. IF so, go your storyboard and to your `UIViewController` you have the `UITableView` placed in and uncheck it's `Under Bottom Bars` boolean.

[image]

**2)** You might have an `NSLayoutConstraint` set at the bottom that is to the negative. Meaning your `UITableView` will be extending to the bottom of the screen. IF so, reset your `UITableView`'s bottom constraint to 0.0.

[image]

**3)** You might want to try using `UITableView` scroll method. Get the index of the last cell:

```
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastCellIndex 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

**4)** `UITableView` is subclassed from `UIScrollView`. Therefore you can treat it as such.

If ever cell in the `UITableView` has the same height, you can multiple the number of objects in your datasource times the height of the cell, then you know what value to enter into your `UIScrollView/TableView` method as contentOffset:

```
(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Great answer @BrandonA. Covered all the bases with nice code snippets.

Comment: @AshleyMills you are far too kind. I am merely a simple programmer. I didn't do anything cool like Reachability for Swift. Yet anyways.

Answer (score 2):

That most probably happen in small iPhone devices. because you didnt set your bottom constraint of the tableview correctly. Check that constraint. if it doesnt exist add it.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to set the automatic dimensions:-

You can pinned your tableView to the superview with the correct constraint and if you are using the custom tableview cell then pinned all the labels constraint (leading, trailing, top and bottom)to the cell and then inside your ViewController `viewDidLoad` method write the below code:-

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

Once your constraints are correct then your table view cell content size will resize dynamically depends on the content.

Note:-

Do not use the tableview delegate method`(heightForRowAtIndexPath)` to adjust the height if you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 0):

In my case...removing

tableview.frame.size = tableview.contentsize worked

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking **"Under Bottom Bars"** of respective ViewController from storyboard inside attribute inspector solved my issue.